# How does a fluid element have vorticity if the stress tensor is symmetric

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity, navier-stokes, vortex

Considering incompressible, Newtonian fluid as an example. The stress tensor is dependent on the symmetric part of the strain rate tensor, which is also symmetric.

What I don't understand is, with a symmetric stress tensor, how is the fluid element undergoing rotation / has vorticity?

Let's say we take the case of a rectangular domain, with an inlet on the left boundary and outlet on the right boundary and a circular cylinder in the domain. Due to the flow around the cylinder, we will have a wake region with vortex shedding and some vorticity I believe. Now in this case how did a fluid element that was not rotating upstream of the cylinder, start to rotate in the wake, in terms of stresses acting on it?

I've gone through these answers, but didn't find an exact answer -

[What causes fluid rotation in the Navier--Stokes equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/354720/what-causes-fluid-rotation-in-the-navier-stokes-equation/354752#354752)

[Can vorticity be destroyed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62056/can-vorticity-be-destroyed)